# Prove $w(t)$ (Bump function) is in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$ (s1.2)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I have to prove that $w(t)$ is in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$,
with $$w(t):= C
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-|x|^2}};& \quad |x|<1,\\
0, &\quad |x| \geq 1,
\end{cases}
$$ where $C > 0$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}w(x)\;dx=1$.

I consider first the function 
$$f(t):=
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{1}{t}}& \quad t<0,\\
0, &\quad t \geq 0,\\
\end{cases}
$$
and check that is continuous in $0$.
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{ e^{\frac{1}{0+h}} - 0}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac {0 -0}{h}$$

Now the function $w(x)$ behave like $f(t)$ in $x=-1$ and $x=1$.
The support is compact, because $w(x)=0$ outside of $[-1,1]$
and being and exponential function $w(x) \in \mathcal{C}^\infty\; \forall \alpha$.

The question is: do I have to ckeck that $\partial^\alpha w(x)$ is continuous in $x=-1$ and $x=1$?